# Записать в массив результат рекурсивной функции

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Есть такая ф-ция:

```
function someFunction($n = 0){
  if($n <= 3) {
    foreach($item_product as $item){
       $arr[] = $item['name'];
    }
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr); echo '</pre>';
    someFunction($n+1);
  }
}
```

На выходе три раза повторяется массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name1
    [1] => name2
    [2] => name3
)
Array
(
    [0] => name4
    [1] => name5
    [2] => name6
)
Array
(
    [0] => name7
    [1] => name8
    [2] => name9
)
```

А как бы все это записать в один такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name1
    [1] => name2
    [2] => name3
    [3] => name4
    [4] => name5
    [5] => name6
    [6] => name7
    [7] => name8
    [8] => name9
)
```

Хочу отметить что переменная $n тут не просто так, она очень важна, т.к. подставляется в запрос, который подразумевает использование нумерации страниц, т.е. сначала вытаскиваем все данные со страниц 1,2,3 по очереди, и хотелось бы чтобы на выходе был не постраничный результат, а все в одном массиве.

Comment: внутри функции объявите массив `$arr` глобальным: `global $arr;`

Comment: Tunker, что-то не очень понимаю как это поможет? Объявил и ничего не изменилось... Я понимаю что нужно ф-цию, которая вызывает саму себя 3 раза, как-то смержить, т.е. что-то типа array_merge(someFunction($n+1)); но это не работает...

Comment: в главной функции создаёте массив и передаёт её аргументом в рекурсивную функцию. `function someFunction($n = 0){$arr= array();recursiveFunction(n,arr);} function recursiveFunction($n, &$arr){..}`

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно возвращать результат работы функции и объединять его.

```
function someFunction($n = 0){

    $result = [];

    //$item_product ???
    $item_product = [
        ['name' => 'name1'],
        ['name' => 'name2'],
        ['name' => 'name3'],
        ['name' => 'name4'],
        ['name' => 'name5'],
    ];

    if($n <= 3) {
        $arr = [];
        foreach($item_product as $item){
            $arr[] = $item['name'];
        }
        $result = array_merge($arr, someFunction($n+1));
    }

    return $result;
}
var_dump(someFunction());
```

Comment: evgen_dev - супер! Спасибо!

Comment: Tunker - Спасибо!